# routes as: path variable not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following route

```
  resources :projects do
    collection do
      get 'svdbf', to: 'projects#new', as: 'otherstuff'
    end
  end
```

and I am trying to make this link work on the view

```
<%= link_to 'Other Stuff', otherstuff_url %>
```

But it's returning the following rails error:

```
undefined local variable or method `otherstuff_url'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the rake routes output you posted, a working path would be

```
<%= link_to 'Other Stuff', otherstuff_projects_path %>
```

Comment: But using the `:as` shouldn't I be able to rename the id of that route?

Comment: I'm going strictly from the rake output. It may not be the path you want, but it should be a working path. Might help to debug and see where it gets you.

Answer (score 0):

Please run `rake routes` from the console. That will give you a full list of routes as well as a list of helper functions available to you.

Also try `otherstuff_path` instead og `otherstuff_url`

Comment: It shows that this on that route `otherstuff_projects GET      /projects/svdbf(.:format)    projects#new` I have tried both those routes and none worked